# How to create many files through the windows 10 command line using a for-loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am creating a directory that stores many years.  I don't want to create one by one because it will take a long time.  As an example, how would I create html files from the year 1980 to 2014 using a for loop in windows command line?  Furthermore, is it possible to edit the contents of the file to contain text with its corresponding year?  I need this for my programming project.

I have the command line open to the desired directory.

Comment: For future reference: Questions regarding command-line use go on [su] instead. If you're trying to script or program something for automation using a batch file (multiple commands sequentially), you can ask here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily from the command line, using `for`. Test first using `echo`, as I've done

```
for /L %i in (1980,1,2014) do echo %i
```

Replace the `echo` with whatever you want to use to generate HTML. (The command line doesn't do that for you, unless you just want an empty file.) The easiest way might be to create a template file (something like *base.html*) and then just copy it in the loop:

```
for /L %i in (1980,1,2014) do copy base.html %i.html
```

The documentation for *for* (available by typing `for /?` or `help for` at the command prompt) says in part:

> FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
>
> So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
>       generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)